# AngularJS: Are there multiple ways to apply ng-model to a form?

Tags: angularjs, playframework, play-bootstrap

I'm using Scala-Play with the Play-Bootstrap extension and AngularJS. Since the controlling of the application is managed by AngularJS I need the form to be submitted and the response managed by AngularJS and not by the Play controller.

As I understand and using pure AngularJS one can use `ng-model` to link each input to a specific `$scope` nested variable e.g.

```
<form name="userForm">
    <label>
      Name:
      <input type="text" name="userName"
             ng-model="user.name"/>
    </label><br />
    <label>
      Other data:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.data" />
    </label><br />
</form>
```

is it possible to accomplish the same by using `ng-model` on the `form` tag? instead of applying it to each input? the problem is that it is not possible injecting the needed `ng-model` to each input while using [Play-Bootstrap](http://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/) i.e. this doesn't work:

```
@b3.text(computeInSampleForm("impliedVolSpread"), '_label -> messagesApi("myapp.impliedVolSpread"), 
         '_showConstraints -> false, 'ng-model -> "impliedVolSpread")
```

it fails with error `value - is not a member of Symbol` it would work if I only knew how to escape the - dash character.

Since I already created a customized version of the `b3.form` as `b3.bgform` it would be great if I could do `bg-model` at the form level ... is that possible?

Comment: You nailed it Sr. it works perfectly!! Can you make an answer and I will accept ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this error by explicitly converting to a Symbol:

```
Symbol("ng-model") -> "impliedVolSpread"
```

Or by using an implicit conversion import:

```
@import views.html.helper.Implicits._
```